# How to display enumerate subitem with overlays?

Tags: beamer, enumerate, overlays

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Tempo de Execução e Tamanho da Entrada}     
   \Large{}
   
   \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
      \justifying      
      \item O desempenho total do sistema depende da escolha de \textbf{algoritmos eficientes} tanto quanto da escolha de hardware rápido;
      \item Analisar um algoritmo significa prever os recursos de que o algoritmo necessita:
      \begin{enumerate}[<.->]
         \item Memória;
         \item Largura de banda de comunicação (rede);
         \item Hardware de computador;
         \item Tempo de computação.
       \end{enumerate} 
   \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**The results:**

[image]

How to appear one-by-one item and subitems? How to place the sub-items in the format 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and 2.4 together with the overlay of the slides?

Comment: (1) Please make sure your example actually compiles (`\justifying` is not defined), (2) ` \Large{}` does not make sense as `\Large` does not take any arguments. (3) Why `[<.->]` on the inner list and not `[<+->]`. If that does not help please rephrase the last paragraph as I don't quite understand what you mean there.

Comment: Hello, @daleif, thank you very much for your help! I edited my question with the necessary package. I made the modification you suggested and the overlay part worked, but I can't number the sub-items in 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and 2.4 when I add `[<+ ->]`. I've tried to do something like `\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*., <+ ->]` but it didn't work. The `\Large{}` command is empty, as I only used it to increase the font size.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy interface for this numbering in beamer, the normal ways with the enumitem package (you used some of its syntax) is not compatible with beamer. The numbering scheme seems unrelated to your original question so it might be an idea to make a new more focus question on that particular problem

Answer (score 2):

To enumerate the subitems with `2.1` etc. you can use the `default` template for the `enumerate subitem`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}[default]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Tempo de Execução e Tamanho da Entrada}     
   \Large{}
   
   \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
      \justifying      
      \item O desempenho total do sistema depende da escolha de \textbf{algoritmos eficientes} tanto quanto da escolha de hardware rápido;
      \item Analisar um algoritmo significa prever os recursos de que o algoritmo necessita:
      \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
         \item Memória;
         \item Largura de banda de comunicação (rede);
         \item Hardware de computador;
         \item Tempo de computação.
       \end{enumerate} 
   \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]